# PHP codeigniter to get categories and subcategories where subcategories list is seperated by comma

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two database tables Categories and Subcategories. In Categories table, there is a field subcategories id where I have stored subcategories id separated by comma. I need to get categories and subcategories. But I am getting only last value of subcategories

```
    //Model
public function getsubCategoriesbyId($subCategoriesId){
        $this->db->select('subCategoriesId, subCategoriesName');
        $condition = array('subCategoriesId'=>$subCategoriesId);
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $query = $this->db->get('subCategories');
        return $query->result();
    }
public function getAllCategories(){
            $this->db->select('categoriesId, categoriesName, subCategoriesList');
            $query = $this->db->get('categories');
            $return = array();
            foreach($query->result() as $categoriesList){
                $return[$categoriesList->categoriesId]=$categoriesList;
                $subCategoriesIdArray= explode(',', $categoriesList->subCategoriesList);
                foreach($subCategoriesIdArray as $subCategoriesId){
                           $return[$categoriesList->categoriesId]->subCategories = $this->getsubCategoriesbyId($subCategoriesId);
                }
            }
            return $return;
        }
      //Controller
public function mycontroller()
{
        $data['categories_list']=$this->myModel->getAllCategories();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data['categories_list']);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
}
      //View
Array
    (
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [categoriesId] => 1
            [categoriesName] => Nepal
            [subCategoriesList] => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
            [subCategories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [categoriesId] => 6
                            [categoriesName] => Volunteer Tour
                        )

                )

        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please update your code with below one

```
foreach($subCategoriesIdArray as $subCategoriesId){
    $return[$categoriesList->categoriesId]->subCategories = $this->getsubCategoriesbyId($subCategoriesId);
}
```

to

```
foreach($subCategoriesIdArray as $subCategoriesId){
    $return[$categoriesList->categoriesId]->subCategories[] = $this->getsubCategoriesbyId($subCategoriesId);
}
```

Use [] and check isset too

Comment: can you help me out showing each value of array in view?

Comment: first tell me does the problem solved? of subcategories